# Send database test E-Mail exception - lock request time out period exceeded

Tags: sql-server, database

I am troubleshooting an error with database mail, and when I went to management->database mail to send a test e mail, I get the following erorr:

```
An exception occured while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
(Microsoft.SQLServer.ConnectionInfo)
Additional information:
Lock request time out period exceeded
The statement has been terminated (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1222)
```

When I investigate this further by looking at all blocking transactions on msdb, I find one transaction, that has the name "implicit transaction". Is this the one which is blocking? What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out what happened by looking at all transactions (right click -> reports -> all transactions). From there I found that a server user had a locking transaction open. After making him close it, everything went fine.